# LIKE keyword in VB6

Tags: vb6, keyword

I saw an example code as below

```
If numb Like "[0-9]" Then
End If
```

Here `numb` is a string holding one character.

What is the LIKE keyword in VB6? Is there any documentation available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Like Operator (Visual Basic for Applications Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242817(v=vs.60).aspx)

> Used to compare two strings.
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> result = string Like pattern
> ```

Comment: I have used VB since 1993 ... and I didn't know that... I learn something everyday :)

Comment: I've been using VB just as long (not too many of us out there), but didn't know about this either. However, I couldn't get the charlist to work.

Comment: These all produced false: "ABC" like "[AZ]", "ABC" like "[A-Z]", "ABC" like "[!Q]". I'm not too worried about it though since I can always just use RegEx.

Comment: @TomCollins They should produce `False`. The `Like` pattern must match the whole string, not a substring. In terms of regex, the `Like` pattern always implicitly starts with `^` and ends with `$`. In order to match `"ABC"` with `Like`, you'd use `"[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"`. So `Like` is a very basic thing that sometimes saves you an effort of linking to a regex library. Mostly when you want to know if a string starts with someting (`s Like "this*"`), ends with something (`s Like "*this"`) or contains something (`s Like "*this*"`).

Comment: Something like `Text1.Text Like "*[!0-9]*"` can be useful for validation (returns True if the String is not all digits).

Answer (score 0):

To have "Like" comparing the string "ABC", you must use * to mean "0 or any number of".

E.g:  "ABC" Like "[A-Z]" results FALSE because "ABC" is not a 1-char long string,
but "ABC" Like "*[A-Z]" returns TRUE because "ABC" has many chars in A-Z range

Cheers... Jorge

Answer (score 0):

**Examples:**

```
"G??" Like "God"
```

To find sentences that must have 3 characters start with capital **G**

```
"Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)" Like "Prophet*"
```

To find sentences with any length but start with **Prophet**

```
"*Islam*" Like "The only logical religion is Islam but they are adding rumors to it"
```

To find sentences with any length that contains **Islam**

```
"##days" Like "40days"
```

To find sentences that must have 6 characters and must start with 2 numbers and must end with days

```
"Only[01234][34]DaysDon'tDoSinThenYou'llSeeTheReality" Like "Only40DaysDon'tDoSinThenYou'llSeeTheReality"
```

Everything inside **[ ]** means: **OR**

**0 OR 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4**

**3 OR 4**

If you input one of them in the exact location. it returns true

In the following example, I **must** use the pattern otherwise I'll get error while typing:

```
Private Sub Text2_Change()

With Text2
    If .Text Like "*/*/####" Then
        .ToolTipText = DATE_TOOLTIP_ADDED(.Text)
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: The only logical religion is Islam eh? Lulz