# VBA - Like operator vs Regular expression (VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5)

Tags: regex, vba

While coding in VBA, I mostly use the VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 reference for my Regex needs, and I have never really used the "Like" operator.

Can someone explain to me what are the differences and possible limitations of those two methods?

Does it only lie in the options you can set in VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 (ignorecase, global, etc.) or the possibility of having alternates ([a|e])?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15475919/11683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Like` is much more limited than regex, but doesn't have the overhead of installing the regex engine.

If you click into the word Like in the VB Editor and press F1, the help page describes the entirety of how it works in a few paragraphs.

Added: There is so much more than just the options to distinguish between them. Regex has repetition, grouping, back-references. This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic1) is excellent on VBScript Regex.

Comment: I have read the help page before asking the question, an understood that it had limitations. I was asking if it was only about the options. So far it seems that way, with also the fact that it doesn't return partial and submatches, unlike VBScript Regex (that part I had missed the first time around). Thanks for the answer, it got me to read the help page again and catch that.

Comment: @Andy G, the MSDN page link you have provided is for the 5.0 version, not 5.5. Is that ok? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is okay.