# How do I use LIKE in IF statement properly in ASP Classic?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a IF statement where I need to use LIKE to determin if the result set contains an e-mail address, and this is similar to the session ADMail .. the initial code I have tried with is :

```
UserEmailForTask = Session("ADmail")


IF objGetTaskEmailsSettings("IT_Email") LIKE %UserEmailForTask% OR Session("ADdepartment") = "IT" THEN

  Dim IT_User_Tasks
  IT_User_Tasks = "YES"

END IF
```

`objGetTaskEmailsSettings("IT_Email")` can contain eigther "user1@mail.com" or have multiple emails inside it like "user1@mail.com,user2@mail.com,user3@mail.com" where I need to check if the email in `UserEmailForTask` is included.

Obviously I will get a fail on `%UserEmailForTask%`when using this, but how do I solve this?

Comment: Hi @Filburt .. this throws me a "Sub or Function not defined" .

Comment: For reference `Like` is a VB operator not VBScript - [LIKE keyword in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15475919)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InStr](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp) function returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another. Use it to check if the given string contains the search string:

```
UserEmailForTask = "..."

IF InStr(objGetTaskEmailsSettings("IT_Email"),UserEmailForTask)>0 
      OR Session("ADdepartment") = "IT" THEN

  Dim IT_User_Tasks
  IT_User_Tasks = "YES"

END IF
```

Comment: Thanks @user2316116 that was perfect, works like a charm :-)

Comment: This has been answered before - [VBS using LIKE to compare strings "Sub or Function not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30301238)